# Local static variable not initialized in Release builds if used only in lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lambda

See code below. Correct output is "10 20 30 ", but in Release builds its "0 0 0 ". Why does this happen?

```
  std::vector<int> inValues = {1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<int> outValues(inValues.size());

  static const int mag = 10;

  std::transform(inValues.cbegin(), inValues.cend(), outValues.begin(), 
    [](const auto value){
    return value * mag;
  });

  for (const auto value: outValues)
    std::cout << value << " ";
```

If variable is mentioned anywhere inside function, or is declared in global scope, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking of capturing variables in lambdas, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation says:

> A variable can be used without being captured if it does not have automatic storage duration (i.e. it is not a local variable or it is static or thread local)

Your variable *is* "static local" thus should be captured automatically.

Additionally [Microsoft gives this example of using a local static storage element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx):

```
void fillVector(vector<int>& v)  
{  
    // A local static variable.  
    static int nextValue = 1;  

    // The lambda expression that appears in the following call to  
    // the generate function modifies and uses the local static   
    // variable nextValue.  
    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [] { return nextValue++; });   
    //WARNING: this is not thread-safe and is shown for illustration only  
}
```

This does work as intended although your example does not.

**This is a [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) bug.** I can report that it has been cleared up in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017). So while you can feel free to report this as a bug, I'd suggest just upgrading to Visual Studio 2017. If you do choose to report it, I'd encourage you to link the bug report here.

Comment: I thought you don't need to capture static variables?

Comment: @frslm You're right good call. This is a Visual Studio bug. Have a +1 for finding the Easter egg.

Comment: Tried to build with clang toolset and it works perfectly. Yeah, its a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it looks like `mag` is set to 0 on compilation; Visual Studio doesn't seem to realise that it's actually used in the lambda expression.

You could change `mag` to be a `const int` only; if you've defined it in a function, then there's arguably little benefit to be gained from defining an `int` as a `static const` compared to just a `const`.

Otherwise, if you're adamant about keeping the `static` qualifier, you could pretend to use `mag` right after you define it, just so its value isn't optimized away upon compilation:

```
static const int mag = 10;
(void)mag; // (pretend to use mag)
```

Comment: No, `static const` was used here by coincidence, it's not a good practice anyway. Mentioning `mag` inside the function only masks the compiler bug.